# Принудительное обновление привязки в wpf

Tags: wpf

Добрый день!

Подскажите, как уведомить приемник привязки при изменении Test1 и Test2?
Привязка осуществляется к All

```
public class Test
{
  public ObservableCollection<Test1> Tests1{ get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<Test2> Tests2{ get; set; }

   public ObservableCollection<object> All
    {
        get
        {
            ObservableCollection<object> all = new ObservableCollection<object>();
            foreach (var test1 in this.Test1)
            {
                all.Add(test1);
            }
            foreach (var test2 in this.Test2)
            {
                all.Add(test2);
            }

            return all;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во первых реализуйте интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged если этого еще не сделали. Затем подпишитесь на изменение коллекций `Test1` и `Test2`, в обработчике вызывайте `PropertyChanged`:

```
public Test()
{ 
    Test1 = new ObservableCollection<object>();
    Test2 = new ObservableCollection<object>();
    Test1.CollectionChanhed += Test_CollectionChanged;
    Test2.CollectionChanhed += Test_CollectionChanged;
}

private void Test_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    /*PropertyChanged("All");*/
}
```

По идее вам нужно добавлять только новые элементы, поэтому можете добавлять элементы из `e.NewItems` к коллекции `All`, тогда вызывать `PropertyChanged("All")` не нужно:

```
private void Test_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{        
    foreach(var item in e.NewItems)
    {
        All.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Eще смотрите на `e.Action`, какое там будет значение (добавление, удаление и т.д.) и соответственно от значения изменяйте вашу общую коллекцию.

Answer (score 1):

У вас изначально неверный подход.

Во-первых, сводить `ObservableCollection<Test1>` & `ObservableCollection<Test2>` к  `ObservableCollection<object>` - это крайне неправильно. Это также неправильно, как сделать из `List<int>` -> `List<object>` или `ArrayList`. Если вы хотите получить обобщающую коллекцию, то следовало создать еще один класс `Test3`, который включал бы в себя два свойства типов: `Test1` и `Test2`, а потом сделать `ObservableCollection<Test3>`.

Во-вторых, сама по себе `ObservableCollection` включает в себя механизм "оповещения" `ComboBox` или `ListView` об изменении состава своих элементов. Из этого следует, что `ObservableCollection` должна быть на "передовой" привязки к нужному контролу, а для всего остального существуют `List<T>` и проч. типы коллекций, поэтому `ObservableCollection<Test1>` & `ObservableCollection<Test2>`, если только они не привязаны, вообще бесполезны в вашем примере.

В-третьих, `ObservableCollection<Test3>` и проч. свойства, которые будут привязаны к контролам должны быть размещены в классе ViewModel, а не в абы каком-то `public class Test`, который вы потом, видимо, собирались использовать во ViewModel.

В-четвертых, все свойства имеющие привязку к контролам в UI, в том числе и свойства с типом `ObservableCollection<T>` должны оповещать UI о своем изменении с помощью вызова события `PropertyChanged` в сеттере свойства.

Comment: Честно говоря так и не понял как прикрутить ObservableCollection<Test3>. Test1 и Test2  разные классы с разными свойствами и только предложенный выше вариант у меня заработал.

Comment: "...разные классы с разными свойствами..." и зачем тогда эти разные классы запихивать в одну общую коллекцию? Как вы дальше используете эту объединенную коллекцию разнородных объектов, можно узнать?

Comment: Строится дерево, дело в том, что дерево необходимо построить так, чтобы класс Test1 имел в себе коллекцию Test2 + коллекцию самого себя (Test1)